# how can i pass a value from UI by parameter in Telerik report?

Tags: asp.net, telerik, reporting, telerik-reporting

i  have drastically problem with Telerik reporting version of 2013 Q1.  it use dll instead of RDLC file. i create a DLL of my reporting and i use this dll in my web application and show it with report viewer. i want in the webpage of my app that report viewer are there, some text box existed for user entry like user typed title of report iT means the user entry show in a report text box value  ,i use parameter but it show me null value . my question is :
how can i do this work by parameter ?
whats wrong in my code ?

```
  using System;
    using System.Collections.Generic;
    using System.Linq;
    using System.Web;
    using System.Web.UI;
    using System.Web.UI.WebControls;
    using schduleing_report;//its my dll

    namespace web.UI.Reports
    {
        public partial class ReportSchdule : System.Web.UI.Page
        {
            protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
            {
               Report2 report = new Report2();

                report.ReportParameters.Add("name",Telerik.Reporting.ReportParameterType.String,"sutytehjj");

                report.ReportParameters["name"].Value = "123";
//it just for test i use it insted of textbox1.text
             //  report.ReportParameters["name"].Value = TextBox1.Text;
                report.ReportParameters["name"].Visible = true;
```

and in my report dll i have text box that the value of it is this = Parameters.name.Value

Answer (score 0):

I guess you have already specified the data source, Data Member or Parameter, if you are using object data source or any data source, example like this http://screencast.com/t/PGKj6EQUVMfC .

```
var instanceReportSource = new Telerik.Reporting.InstanceReportSource();
            instanceReportSource.ReportDocument = new ReportLib.Report1();
            instanceReportSource.Parameters.Add("name", 123);
            this.ReportViewer1.ReportSource = instanceReportSource;
```

I hope it will help you

Comment: thanks for your answer but it doesn't work i create  a parameter like picture to my sqldatasource and i use it in one of text box in my report and i test your code but it dose not show me it value